# v-for prop value not getting updated with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code snippet

```
<div class="list-group-item media" v-for="evt in event">

    <eventmodal :currentevent = "evt"></eventmodal>

</div>
```

The problem that I am facing is that in the prop, I am always getting the first value. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?  I am using vuejs 2.0

Also, I am wondering if I can set the props of a child component programmatically?

This is how my child component looks

```
    <template>
    <div class="card content">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            <span v-if="currentevent">{{currentevent.title}}</span>
            <span v-else>New Event</span>
        </h4>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter event title here" class="form-control" v-model="title">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        <textarea class="note-view__body" id="eventDescription" v-model="description" placeholder="enter event description"></textarea>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter organizer name here" class="form-control" v-model="organizer">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="start date" class="form-control" v-model="startdate">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="end date" class="form-control" v-model="enddate">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control" v-model="email">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="phone" class="form-control" v-model="phone">
            <i class="form-group__bar"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="button" v-on:click="clear()" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" v-on:click="performSave()" class="btn btn-link">Save</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    props:['currentevent'],
    data() {
            return {
                title: '',
                description: '',
                organizer: '',
                startdate: '',
                enddate: '',
                email: '',
                phone: ''
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.makeTextBoxReady();

        },
        methods: {
            makeTextBoxReady: function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    if (!$('html').is('.ie9')) {
                        if ($('.note-view__body')[0]) {
                            $('.note-view__body').trumbowyg({
                                autogrow: true,
                                btns: [
                                    'btnGrp-semantic', ['formatting'],
                                    'btnGrp-justify',
                                    'btnGrp-lists', ['removeformat']
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            performSave : function() {
                let description = $('#eventDescription').trumbowyg('html');

                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('title',this.title);
                formData.append('desciption',description);
                formData.append('startdate',this.startdate);
                formData.append('enddate',this.enddate);
                formData.append('organizer',this.organizer);
                formData.append('email',this.email);
                formData.append('phone',this.phone);
                // formData.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN',document.querySelector('#_token').getAttribute('content'));
                console.log("going to save event information");
                this.$http.post('/admin/event/create', formData).then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response.data.status==200) {
                        alert(response.data.message);
                        this.$emit('get_events');
                    }
                })
            },

            clear: function() {
                this.title = '';
                this.description = '';
                this.organizer = '';
                this.startdate = '';
                this.enddate = '';
                this.email = '';
                this.phone = '';
            }
        }
}
</script>
```

Events (which are being iterated) ...

An event (in context of my application) is a thing that happens, much like Google Events. The user will create events and they will be rendered on a calendar control.

There are currently 3 events in the system. All of them are listed here. I can also vouch for the fact that they do get loaded up properly in the "events" in the v-for. Its just the prop value is always the first one. In VueJs 1.0 i could easily do sync and it would sync the prop with the correct value that was being iterated , but I beleive that they have been taken away.

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "15-17",
    "desciption": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, deserunt.",
    "eventscategory_id": 1,
    "startdate": "2016-10-11 03:09:15",
    "enddate": "2016-10-17 19:12:15",
    "organizer": "another user",
    "street": null,
    "street2": null,
    "city": null,
    "province": null,
    "country": null,
    "phone": null,
    "email": "test123@test.com",
    "fax": null,
    "created_at": "2015-09-21 19:12:15",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-11 10:51:53",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "title": "latest event",
    "desciption": "",
    "eventscategory_id": 1,
    "startdate": "2017-01-01 00:00:00",
    "enddate": "2017-01-03 00:00:00",
    "organizer": "a user",
    "street": null,
    "street2": null,
    "city": null,
    "province": null,
    "country": null,
    "phone": "5197293401",
    "email": "auser@gmail.com",
    "fax": null,
    "created_at": "2016-12-16 06:32:53",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-16 06:32:53",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "title": "check for description",
    "desciption": "",
    "eventscategory_id": 1,
    "startdate": "2017-10-10 00:00:00",
    "enddate": "2017-10-10 00:00:00",
    "organizer": "test organizer",
    "street": null,
    "street2": null,
    "city": null,
    "province": null,
    "country": null,
    "phone": "12345",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "fax": null,
    "created_at": "2016-12-16 06:43:04",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-16 06:43:32",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: In vuejs 2.0 setting the value prop on a child component is like a v-model. And you can programmatically set props using a render function

Comment: @vbranden can you please show me an example or point me a link please ?

Comment: render functions https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments , and this guide indirectly explains how the value prop is like v-model https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Comment: @vbranden : I am already doing that  <eventmodal :currentevent = "evt"></eventmodal>.

Comment: if you want to use 2 way bindings on a component, you need to use `v-model` not `:currentevent` and the child has to have a prop named `value` the `value` prop can be edited like a 2way prop. The second link i posted goes over that.

Comment: @vbranden : I did what you suggested, but I am getting the following error in that case : template syntax error <eventmodal v-model="event">: You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.

Comment: @vbranden so instead of passing the entire object, i just passed the title , but I got the same old result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to add [key](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) in [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for)

```
<div class="list-group-item media" v-for="evt in event" :key="evt.id">
    <eventmodal :currentevent="evt"></eventmodal>
</div>
```

For the improvement of performance, v-for uses an “in-place patch” strategy and list rendering will not change on child component state or temporary DOM state changes. To track these changes you need to add key attribute with v-for.

I hope spaces are just typo in `<eventmodal :currentevent = "evt"></eventmodal>`, remove spaces from `:currentevent = "evt"`.

---

### Edited

You are showing same modal everytime, props are being passed correctly, but you are loading the same modal each time.

You should have [dynamic id](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) for each modal like following:

```
<eventmodal :id="evt.id" :currentevent="evt"></eventmodal>
```

and when you are showing this, you should use this dynamic id as following:

```
$("#" + event.id).modal()
```

Comment: I updated the code as you suggested but I am still encountering the issue.. there are no errors that I am encountering..