# trumbowyg editor with vuejs

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the [trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) editor control in my vuejs spa. From [the documentation](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html#manage-content) I know that I can use the following code to set the contents of the editor.

```
$('#editor').trumbowyg('html','<p>Your content here</p>'); 
$('#editor').trigger('tbwchange');
```

However, it is not working for me in my VueJs App. I have an object that has a description key defined. I can `console.log` the description , but when I try to assign it to the editor control as mentioned above, it fails . I can see no error in the `console` but the text just won't show up in the editor.

Here is what I am going at the moment.

```
<template>
    <div class="modal fade"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        <span v-if="anouncement">Edit Anouncement</span>
                        <span v-else>New Anouncement</span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter anouncement summary here" class="form-control" v-model="anouncementObj.summary">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="enter location here" class="form-control" v-model="anouncementObj.location">
                    </div>
                    <textarea class="note-view__body" id="anonDescription" v-model="description" placeholder="enter event description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="clear()" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="performSave()" class="btn btn-link">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props : {
            anouncement : Object
        },
        data() {
            return {
                anouncementObj :{}
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            this.makeTextBoxReady();
            this.anouncementObj = Object.assign({},this.anouncementObj, this.anouncement || {});
                $('#anonDescription').trumbowyg('html',this.anouncement.description); 
                $('#anonDescription').trigger('tbwchange');
                console.log(this.anouncement.description);
        },
        methods : {
            makeTextBoxReady: function() {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    if (!$('html').is('.ie9')) {
                        if ($('.note-view__body')[0]) {
                            $('.note-view__body').trumbowyg({
                                autogrow: true,
                                btns: [
                                    'btnGrp-semantic', ['formatting'],
                                    'btnGrp-justify',
                                    'btnGrp-lists', ['removeformat']
                                ]
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            performSave : function() {
                let description = $('#anonDescription').trumbowyg('html');

                let formData = new FormData();
                for (name in this.anouncementObj) {
                    formData.append(name, this.anouncementObj[name]);
                }

                if( !this.anouncementObj.id) {
                    this.anouncementObj.id = 0;
                }

                formData.append('description',description);

                this.$http.post('/admin/anouncement/createOrUpdate', formData).then(response => {
                    // console.log(response);
                    if(response.data.status==200) {
                        alert(response.data.message);
                        this.$emit('getAnouncements');
                    }
                })
            },
            clear: function() {
                this.anouncementObj= {};
            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?  I have also tried the `nexttick` approach but even that is not working.

Comment: I'd suggest step into `$('#anonDescription').trumbowyg('html',this.anouncement.description);` to see what code is executed and make another simpler example where the same method works, step into it too, find what's different between those two calls to our critical method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I was not using the correct bootstrap modal id. Please see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191789/v-for-prop-value-not-getting-updated-with-bootstrap-modal) for more information.

This is the correct code.

```
if(this.anouncementObj && this.anouncementObj.description && this.anouncementObj.id) {
   $('#'+this.anouncementObj.id+' #anonDescription').trumbowyg('html',this.anouncementObj.description); 
   $('#'+this.anouncementObj.id+' #anonDescription').trigger('tbwchange');
}
```