# How to correctly update value for v-for prop in bootstrap modal class

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

Am having this code in my parent component

```
<div v-for="contestant in contestants" :key="contestant.id">
    <Evidence :contestant="contestant"></Evidence>
</div>
```

Then in my child component as below

```
<template>
<span @click="showModal(contestant)">View supporting evidence</span>
                         <!-- Evidence -->
                         <div class="modal fade" id="claimEvidence" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title text-primary" id="addNewLabel">Evidence to support {{username}}'s claim.</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close text-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>{{firstname}} {{lastname}}</p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
</template>

 <script>
  export default {
    props: ['contestant'],
    data(){
      return{
          firstname: '',
          lastname: '',
          username: '',
       }
    },
    methods:{
       showModal(contestant){
          $('#claimEvidence').modal('show');
          this.username = contestant.user.username
          this.firstname = contestant.user.first_name
          this.lastname = contestant.user.last_name
      }
    }
  }
```

The issue that am experiencing is that am **always getting the first value of the iteration** rather than looping through the iteration in my bootstrap modal class. Am guessing the problem is with the **prop** **because when i use the same modal class directly into my parent component, it works correctly**. I found this similar **[issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191789/v-for-prop-value-not-getting-updated-with-bootstrap-modal)** but I could not figure out how. Please can someone help me figure out what am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41194863/9541423) answered your problem in the "Edited" part.

Fix your loop by adding dynamic `id` selectors:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="`claimEvidence-${contestant.id}`" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addNewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
methods:{
   showModal(contestant){
      $('#claimEvidence-' + contestant.id).modal('show');
      //...
   }
}
```

Comment: wow cool. I now get it. I was passing the dynamic id only in the method but not in the modal class as well.